# Connecting via VPN - could they see what sites I am using

Tags: vpn, privacy

I use a Critrix VPN to login to work. When I'm logged on via this, I can't even access my own LAN.

When this VPN is connected, I RDP into my machine and work from home.

My concern is, I looked at a website on my local computer (job sites) and I'm very concerned the company can see this website and know I'm looking at other jobs.

My question is, when I use a VPN, does all internet traffic go via the VPN? So, whilst my VPN is open, if I open IE and type a web page, is that page actually being retrieved from my company's ISP, and then passed through the VPN to my computer?

Comment: If you are concerned you might considering not looking at job sites while connected to the VPN.  While connnected to the VPN all traffic is sent through the VPN server.  Just like your ISP knows what websites you have visted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick way to know if the VPN is used for surfing is using [monip.org](http://monip.org/).

Visit this site with VPN offline, note the IP address displayed. Repeat the process with VPN online. If the two noted IP address are the same, its OK, your surf can not be monitored. If the two IP are different, your company may be able to know the sites you visit.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: It depends on the settings of your computer and the VPN settings at your company.